# Can Neo4j data be exported or converted to linkML format data?

Tags: json, neo4j, rdf, linkml

Is it possible to export or convert neo4j data to linkML format, and if so, can this process be reversible?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to do? In LinkML, instance data requires a schema, so perhaps this is in two parts: How do I make a LinkML schema from Neo4J, and then how do a export data conformant with that schema?